# MS SQL Server Management copy database schedule

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I set up a copying database (every hour) from one to another server with copy wizard (right click to database Tasks - Copy) in MS SQL Server Management Studio. How can I edit or remove this schedule? I can't find it anywhere. There is nothing in SQL Server Agent.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked jobs folder under SQL Server Agent?

Comment: What do you mean edit or remove the schedule? As your'e the one doing it, if you want to "remove" it just stop doing it. As for editting the schedule, change when you do it I *assume* what you're actually after is automatiion What copy method are you using? But copying a database every hour seems like an XY problem. Why not use Replication?

Comment: @NaveenArora yes I checked job folder under SQL Server Agent, It's not there

Comment: I guess, you don't have access to that.

Comment: @Larnu I use the SQL Management Object method. I have the problem, that the database on destination folder removed, but not copy, so I need stop doing this every hour

Comment: The task is created on the **destintation** server, not the *source*. I just tried, and it creates the job (on the destination server) without issue.

Comment: @Larnu thanks a lot. Job was on destination server